# If the order of $g$ is $32$, find $h \in G$ s.t. $h^5 = g$.

Tags: elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

If the order of $g$ is $32$, does it follow that if $h \in G$ s.t. $h^5 = g$ then $h = g^{-132}$ since $g^{32} = e \implies g^{33} = g \implies (g^{33})^5 = g^5 \implies ((g^{33})^5)^{-4} = g \implies (g^{-132})^5$ = g.

Comment: What's the problem????

Comment: Question: Let $G$ be a group, $g \in G$ s.t. $g^{32} = e$. Find $h \in G$ s.t. $h^5 = g$.

I think I am very confused about how to deal with the exponent notation.

Comment: Note that the cyclic group here is isomorphic to $\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z}$. After all, modulo 32 is the calculation you're already doing! So you should want, in $\mathbb{Z}/32\mathbb{Z}$, some element $x$ such that $5x\equiv1\mod32$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think of it this way: you want to find an element of $G$ which gives $g$ when we multiply it by itself $5$ times. Thus, we can use a power of $g$, such as $g^k$, and we want $5k$ to be one more than a multiple of $32$.

That is, $5k\equiv 1 \pmod{32}$
solve to get $k=13$ (there are multiple solutions, so we picked the easiest).

So we have $h=g^{13}$, and we know $h\in G$. As a check, $h^5=g^{13\cdot 5}=g^{65}=g^{32}g^{32}g=g$.

Comment: Thank you, that makes sense and I see what I did incorrectly.